# How to set two layout one at top and anther at bottom

Tags: android, android-layout

hi I have 2 layout inside a framelayout and i want one linearlayout at top and another at bottom where i will specify height for both the layouts
and how to set this parameter for the linearLayout "layout_gravity " by code not by XML

Comment: You need to properly punctuate your questions.  If they're hard to read, like this one is, you'll end up getting downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Use a surfaceView , the SurfaceView allows you to stack in the Z order.

[Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html)

make sure your surfaceView is under the views of the views you want to stack.

Hope this helps

Comment: thx for the reply but i need to use a layout before using a view,how to set the layout_gravity parameter by code?

Answer (score 0):

first fetch the layout from  id.

```
 LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.IDOFLAYOUT);
```

//the set the gravity by this method

```
 layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

Comment: Aswasthi : Im not using XML to define layouts im coding so i created an layout like this
LinearLayout layer1 = new LinearLayout(this); can set the id as well
but the SetGravity method align the objects inside the linear layout not the layout itself ! so the method u specified wont work :(

Comment: You dont need to add id then, it will work without id too.
second thing , what i got from your question is that you need to show two layouts vertically align. My suggestions are.
1) create 1 layout. add orientation as vertical. gravity as center//or as you like
2) create two more layouts, add them into first one.
3) in second point add margin top in second layout or margin bottom in first layout.  it is gonna help you. 
if not, give a screen shot or scrath how you want it. will draw it and copy code here.

Comment: @Awasthi: thx agian, since im using many layouts within a layout the problem exists and i solved this by this method
LinearLayout sceneLayer = new LinearLayout(this);
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = 
    new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,362,Gravity.TOP);
  sceneLayer.setLayoutParams(params);
and i created other layout and did the same Layoutparams set the Layout gravity, this is already been discussed by an developer in this website, Thxs for your help !